# How to check login and password from DataSource?

Tags: java, oracle, authentication, passwords, datasource

Any user have login/password in Oracle database.
I have a code:

```
Connection con;
Statement stmt = null;
String query = "SELECT user FROM dual";
try {
    dataSource = (DataSource) new InitialContext().lookup("jdbc/MyDataSource");
} catch (NamingException e) {
    throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
}
try {
    System.out.println("name, password:" + name + "|" + password);
    con = dataSource.getConnection(name, password);
    stmt = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    while (rs.next()) {
        System.out.println("User:" + rs.getString("USER"));
    }
    con.close();
    return true;
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(UserInfoServiceOracle.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    return false;
}
```

If I put a correct password, next user could getConnection using any login/password and with login/password from first correct user.

Log:

```
INFO:   name, password:correctUser|correctPassword
INFO:   User:correctUser
INFO:   name, password:jhkjhkjh|khkjhkj
INFO:   User:correctUser
```

Comment: What happens when you do supply the incorrect password in `dataSource.getConnection(name, password)` ?

Comment: It returned connection whithout exception.

Comment: I can't tell for sure what is your problem because you don't post your complete classes. But I guess the reason is because the datasource is still connected using your first username and password

Comment: @kotygoroshko, I suspected that. Check my answer. I have explained this behavior.

Comment: How disconnect DataSource or clear login/password?

Comment: @kotygoroshko, You cannot disconnect from the connection object obtained from datasource neither can you clear the login/password. I guess what you are looking for is an standalone datasource application  .

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Some tool like PhpMyAdmin? Or you want to delegate user authorization to database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A datasource is a facade for a [connection pool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool).

- As confirmed by you. Even if you supply an incorrect password, the datasource returns connection. This means that datasource is not bothering about the username password that you are supplying to it.
- As pointed out by others over here, a datasource is configured and created by the application server. The server reads the appropriate parameters (like, username/password, initial number of connection, max number of connection etc) from a configuration file (some xml) and creates connection (initial no. of connection) to  be used by application later.
- So when you call `dataSource.getConnection`, the datasource is returning *already created connections*. The username/password supplied has no effect.

Comment: If I set login/password in application server.The application ignore any login/password and return connection.

Comment: But if I didn`t set login/password in application server. The application didn`t return connection until I set correct login/password in getConnection(name, password).

Answer (score 1):

Your database credentials are bound to the `DataSource`. Therefore you will always be connected to the database using the credentials supplied to the `DataSource`.

A `DataSource` is a managed resource and it is not intended to connect with other user names.

Depending on your environment you can use the Driver itself to create your own conection but then you will lose all possibilities a `DataSource` provides you (e.g. connection pooling).

In a `Connection` returned by a `DataSource` the method `getConnection()` is a no-op.

Comment: Why DataSource have getConnection(name,password) method?

Comment: It depends on the implementation ([as described in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html)) but most implementations don't support log in to the database.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confusing the security for the database with the security that you should be designing around your application.

Your application knows the credentials to the database (probably through a property file) and builds a datasource.  Users have access to the functionality of your application (and thus the datasource) once they have authenticated themselves with your application.

Comment: I didn`t have any property file whith login/password.

Comment: That's something that you would need to develop yourself to hold the database credentials.  The standard approach is: your application logs into the database, users log into your application.